# How to remove files with wildcard?

Tags: rm, ubuntu-22.04

rm with wildcard is not working.

if there are files that named with ef1 & ef2 then, i tried to erase ef1 & ef2.

$ rm ef*
This could not erase ef1 & ef2.

But like as bellow, single file rm is working.
$ rm ef1
$ rm ef2

Trying to create files to delete with *(asterisk,wildcard)

**asdf@asdf:~/Documents/rust/hello$ touch ef1 ef2**

**asdf@asdf:~/Documents/rust/hello$ ls**

> ef1  ef2  hello  main.rs  test.c  test_c

**asdf@asdf:~/Documents/rust/hello$ rm ef***

> rm: cannot remove 'ef*': No such file or directory

*Why i can not delete ef1 and ef2????*

**asdf@asdf:~/Documents/rust/hello$ rm -r ef***

> rm: cannot remove 'ef*': No such file or directory

**asdf@asdf:~/Documents/rust/hello$ rm -f ef***

**asdf@asdf:~/Documents/rust/hello$ rm -rf ef***

**asdf@asdf:~/Documents/rust/hello$ sudo rm ef***

> rm: cannot remove 'ef*': No such file or directory

**asdf@asdf:~/Documents/rust/hello$ ls**

> ef1  ef2  hello  main.rs  test.c  test_c

*Why i can not delete ef1 and ef2????*

**alias rm**

> bash: alias: rm: not found

**type rm**

> rm is hashed (/usr/bin/rm)

**which rm**

> /usr/bin/rm

**\rm ef***

> rm: cannot remove 'ef*': No such file or directory

**echo $-**

> himBHs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why ubuntu asterisk wildcard is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74459359/why-ubuntu-asterisk-wildcard-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Two days of wasted time...

I have finally found the answer by my self.
Unfortunately, the problem was me my self.

I focused on rm with wildcard works with "sudo -i".
So i checked .bashrc and found the solution with single line.
Once i commented out source ~~~ then problem fixed.

There was bellow line at above source ~~~~.
I dont know why i did that.

#!/bin/sh
#GLOBIGNORE="*"